# NuGet fails: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

Tags: nuget

I want to install Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core through the use of Manage Nuget Packages, but when I click the install button the following error occurs:

*The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send*

Comment: Can you install other packages using NuGet?

Comment: No, I cannot install any package.

Answer (score 113):

**Try pasting the following into a .reg file and run it**. Then try running your NuGet command (no reboot required).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Ran into this issue because TLS1.2 was not enabled (similar to Tony's response). Using *http does **not** fix the situation* because NuGet redirects to https now that TLS1.2 is enforced.

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed the exception when using NuGet in LINQPad 4.

Comment: Nuget has now officially permanently removed support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 from 15th June 2020. See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-org-will-permanently-remove-support-for-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-june-15th/. As a result you may encounter this issue on older Windows platforms (for me it was Windows 2012 R2).

Comment: @karmasponge Just ran into it on Win 7.

Comment: Worked for me i am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Worked for me (SharpDevelop 4.4.1; Win 7).

Comment: Here's the commands you can run directly (instead of messing with .reg files): `reg.exe add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1` `reg.exe add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1`

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Confirmed fix on Windows 8.1 desktop with VS.NET 2013.

Comment: @neoscribe where i can found .reg file?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil it's a text file. You can create it anywhere on the file system where you have permissions. Just paste my solution into your text file, then save your text file with a '.reg' extension. Double-click it and Windows will automatically add it too the registry (if you have permission).

Comment: Worked. VS2013 need to be restarted.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ,it also resolved my issue in Visual Studio 13.

Comment: Wow after banging my head on the wall many, many times to get this fixed.  This did it.  Thanks!

Comment: Fixes Nuget issue in SharpDevelop. Thank you!

Comment: Using VS 2012 on Windows 7 and this answer fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone know of a similar fix to get vs2010 working? I tried it and no joy. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

This is SSL cert issue on http://go.microsoft.com. Change the package source url to http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/ which works for me.

Source: https://github.com/nuget/home

Answer (score 15):

I got this error on an old customer developer VM with Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012:

> Install-Package : An error occurred while loading packages from
>   'https://nuget.org/api/v2/': The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send

[image]

Solved it by going to Tools -> Extensions and Updates... -> Updates -> Visual Studio Gallery and Updated NuGet Package Manager from there.

[image]

After reboot everything worked:

[image]

Comment: This is the answer that solved it for me.  Updating a tool always beats manual registry modifications.

Comment: "Cannot check for updates because an error occurred while trying to contact the server"

Comment: I tried this first on a newly updated Win11 laptop. It did not work for me (errors trying to update NuGet Package Manager). so I added the `SchUseStrongCrypto` registry entries from another post which also did not work. After I restarted I tried updating NuGet Package Manager again and it worked this time. I'm no longer having the problem as the OP. Hard to say what actually fixed though, maybe both were needed in my case.

Comment: For VS 2022, start VS as admin and try Help > Check for Updates a

Answer (score 8):

NuGet has removed support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 as of June 15, 2020.
See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/

If you are using **VS2013** or less you have lost NuGet connectivity as of this date and you will only be able to use NuGet by upgrading at least to **VS2015**, although I would suggest upgrading to **VS2019** to be at the latest at time of this comment.

Comment: This is not in fact true as of July 7, 2020.  Our team is still using VS 2013 and we were able to overcome the error by following the first answer that mentions adding entries to the registry.

Comment: In my case adding to the registry did not  solve the problem. Glad it did for you. However I upgraded my VS 2013 projects to VS 2019. I had to install a few extensions that I had in VS 2013 and other than that it worked well. I did first make a new git branch for the VS upgrade in order to optionally roll back. I noticed there were no git changes other than the code changes I put in myself. Very pleased with VS 2019.

Comment: Yes same problem here with VS2013. Solved by adding registry entries as per top voted answer and restarting VS.

Comment: Fixed it for VS2012 (yay ancient company licenses) by adding the registry entry. Though I added it to the .Net 3.0 and 3.5 ones too for good measure. No idea if that actually does anything, but eh, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if you don't have TSL 1.0 enabled (disabled by default in Server 2012R2). In this case you may see some packages installing successfully before you hit the 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send' error.

For more details on the error, run nuget install from the command line using "Verbosity detailed"

i.e.

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected err
>   or occurred on a receive. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client
>   and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that helped me was switching from Windows 7 to Windows 10.
For people like me who don't really like updates details are described below.

---

As @Rob Farquharson have said above Nuget team threw away support for tls 1.0 and 1.1.

Some confusion is introduced by the fact that the https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json opens perfectly through the browsers. Nevertheless, through Visual Studio we get an error "Unable to load the service index for source".

> [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.   An error occurred while sending
> the request.   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected
> error occurred on a send.   Unable to read data from the transport
> connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host.   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

This happens because the browser like Chrome and Firefox maintain and ship their own ciphers. .NET applications however rely on the ciphers provided by the OS. And therefore no action will help if support is not implemented at the OS level.

Neither suggestions here nor in the question [Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185443/nuget-connection-attempt-failed-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-source) could help me. I've tried approximately 10 various ways to solve the desribed issue.

I've checked registry 3 times. Installed kb3140245 twice and did others stepd for activates tls 1.2, but none of them helped. Updating VS2019 from 16.4 (released in december 2019) to 16.11.8 (released in december 2021) didn't help either.

After that I installed brand new Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 and error went away.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your firewall is doing SSL inspection.  You may need to white list the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is related to the webserver not having a valid SSL certificate. An invalid SSL certificate can be due to it being self-signed and not trusted by a CA, or the certificate has been revoked by the CA.

Using the unauthenticated URL can be a workaround for the issue however the solution to the problem is to ensure the SSL certificate is valid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we have rules blocking .EXE downloads, so we keep a copy of NuGet.exe in the .nuget solution folder, right next to NuGet.targets and NuGet.Config

For whatever reason, this was missing in the new branch.