# NuGet on VS2010 cannot use: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I have installed a NuGet Package Manager 2.8.60318.667 on VS2010 Extension Manager.
However, The Manage Nuget Packages cannot be accessed with prompt of
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"
I have tried the solution in :[NuGet fails: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445638/nuget-fails-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred)
But Failed.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: run `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol-bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`--> `Package Manager Console` and then install the package to test again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried that while the error changed to "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."